# Windows phone 7: Socket does not returns the whole image from server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets, windows-phone-7

I am working on the TCP Socket in windows phone.
i created one application in that i have to receive the image from server.
for that i converted the image in to array of bytes to transfer to windows phone.

But, some times windows phone gets the whole Byte array and some times not getting the whole byte Array of image.

So, here i coded that,

```
public void ReceiveMessage()
{
    var responseListener = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
    responseListener.Completed += OnMessageReceivedFromServer;
    var responseBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    responseListener.SetBuffer(responseBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
    connection.ReceiveAsync(responseListener);
}
```

And after received the message i called the OnMessageReceivedFromServer.

in that

```
public void OnMessageReceivedFromServer(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
   // Convert the received message into a string
      var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesTransferred);

   //trailingmessage is the string declared with null.
   //it will store the message if the message is greater than the bufferSize.
     trailingMessage = trailingMessage + message;
   //This checks wheather the message is remaining or not.
   //if yes then it will again receives the message until it resumes.
     if (e.BytesTransferred > 0 && e.BytesTransferred == bufferSize)
     {
            ReceiveMessage();               
     }
     else
     {
            receivedstring = trailingMessage;
            trailingMessage = null;
            ReceiveMessage();
            onMsg.Invoke(receivedstring);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not safely convert byte array to string and then get the original bytes (using Encoding.GetString, Encoding.GetBytes).

Here is a code showing it wouldn't work

```
byte[] buf = { 255, 255, 255 };
var newBuf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf));
```

**newbuf's content:** `239,191,189,239,191,189,239,191,189`

Comment: @NikhilPrajapati Used what? I said *do not use it*

Comment: yeah..
i mean than i removed it..but still not getting the whole image.
sometimes it receives full byte array of image successfully.
and sometimes it will return with half portion of the byte array.
so, now ??

Comment: @NikhilPrajapati you can not assume you will get all bytes in one read. You should keep reading until all bytes are recevied. To ensure this, you can send the image size before sending the actual image.

Comment: Yes.
Thanks for replying...
i will try it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a string to store your image use a List of bytes:

```
List<byte> trailingBuffer = new List<byte>();
```

The add the received bytes to this list:

```
public void OnMessageReceivedFromServer(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < e.BytesTransferred; i++)
    {
        trailingBuffer.Add(e.Buffer[i]);
    }

    // handling of complete / non-complete message ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This test:

```
 if (e.BytesTransferred > 0 && e.BytesTransferred == bufferSize)
 {
        ReceiveMessage();               
 }
```

is not valid. It is perfectly legitimate to receive the data 1 byte at a time (even if the other end send all the data at once) - in which case *yes* you got data (the `> 0`), but you **did not** get a full buffer (the `== bufferSize`). This is simply *how a stream works* (and sockets typically operate as a stream). You need to *either* keep looping until the end of the stream (`e.BytesTransferred <= 0`), **or** (usually if you want to send several messages on the same socket) you need to implement some form of "framing" - most commonly (since this is binary) by simply writing the expected number of bytes into the stream *first*, and then read exactly that amount.

See also: http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2013/02/how-many-ways-can-you-mess-up-io.html